# link image on the exact "borders" of the image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, hyperlink

I have this problem with linked images. I would like to know if someone has a solution for my problem. I created several images and placed them in the correct order of the picture. I link ed the image to a pop-up box so there should pop-up a resume.

The problem is that the images are overlapping so not al the images are clickable. Is there a way to create a link that is following the exact "borders" of the image?

To see what I mean: http://oege.ie.hva.nl/~gruijsl001/equityestate/team.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

combine the separate images into a single file and use Area tag 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Can i couple this to the fancybox plugin? How would the area tag look like then?

Comment: I have never tried this But from my view it will work.Try it write some code.If any problem than  i am here.

Comment: i tried it, and it worked. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

combine the separate images into a single file and use image maps

Answer (score 1):

-use image mapping concept.

```
<map name="mymap">
<area shape="rectangle" coords="39,31,166,109" href="abc.html">
<area shape="rectangle" coords="188,4,230,126" href="cdf.html">
</map>
```

-map the image according to requirements, and use the ismap or usemap attribute of img tag.